# python 3 requests 'ascii' codec can't encode character

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, ascii

this is the same question asked a million times on SO but I can't find a situation exactly like mine:

```
import requests
url = 'https://markets.ft.com/data/indices/tearsheet/summary?s=TR0000:TOR'
response = requests.get(url)
print (response.text)
```

I get the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u25bc' in position 38113: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This happened for every URL I try.
The response header also says meta/charset 'utf-8' on every URL i try and the response docs say utf-8 is the standard encoding. Can someone please shed some light on this for me?

Answer (score 0):

What IDE are you using? Check your project encoding.  It seems like it's set as us-ascii which is why it's failing.  If you change the project encoding to UTF-8 it'll work.  On my Pycharm I have tried with the file encoding UTF-8, but as long as my project encoding is us-ascii it'll fail.

Output when my project encoding is us-ascii:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Idlehands/PycharmProjects/ForFun/test.py", line 4, in <module>
    print (response.text)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u25bc' in position 38266: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Output when my project encoding is UTF-8:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us" class="no-js core o-hoverable-on">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta name="description" content="S&P/TSX COMPOSITE TOTAL RETURN INDEXindex chart, prices and performance, plus recent news and analysis." />
        <meta name="keywords" content="S&P/TSX COMPOSITE TOTAL RETURN INDEXindex chart, prices and performance, plus recent news and analysis." />
... (snipped)
```

windows-1252 also work.

Comment: sorry for late response. i ended up using urllib.requests and avoided the problem for my specific purpose. when you say "set project encoding to UTF-8" do you mean via `<meta charset="utf-8">` or do you do it in pycharm somewhere? i use Atom for editing.

Answer (score 0):

same pb here with functionnal code in WSL but failing under pure windows (all in vscode)

the error is thrown in the `requests.get(...)`